# How to get permission to use LinkedIn endpoint https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, postman, linkedin-api

I have already created a LinkedIn "Company" using my LinkedIn account that allowed me to create an LinkedIn App. I now a clientID and secret but that only gives me access to certain "company" products like advertising, live events etc

For now I can make an API call to "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo" which just retrieves my name and profile picture. How do I get access to my own information using  "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me".

For now I am getting "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me" and I understand why but where do I get permission to use my app api to get my own data

Thanks in advance

Comment: From your linkedin developer account maybe

Comment: @FolabiAhn thats where I created my API app and I only have access to "company" type endpoints. I dont see any endpoint for accessing my own linkedin data like my profiles, job history etc.

Comment: Have the same problem. I only want to post to the whiteboard of the company. But that requires my personal id. And it seems impossible o get it.